# How to handle ios data from API call

Tags: uitableview, swift, alamofire, swifty-json

When i call api using Alamofire like this

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://localhost:8080/xxx/xxx/xxx/xx").responseJSON() {
        (_, _, jsonData, error) in

        if error == nil{
            var newItem=JSON(jsonData!)
            println(newItem)
        }
        else{
            println("Nothing!")
        }
    }
```

And I got many json format which include {"header","body"}. Header are like this

```
"header" : {
   "toPage" : "3948",
   "totalCount" : "59212",
   "lotId" : "50205",
   "vendorName" : "TOYOTA",
   "rowPerPage" : "15",
   "fromPage" : "1",
   "currentPage" : "1",
   "modelName" : "LEXUS LS"
}
```

The body string include 15 rows per page including many data like this,i gonna show you one only.

```
"body" : [
{
  "id" : "5AxYKWbiqn451Y",
  "priv" : "",
  "average" : "395000",
  "equip" : "",
  "chassis" : "DA63T"
},
```

Everytime i request,it give me 15 results.All i want is to show this in table view using table cell,label and image view [like this](http://puu.sh/fv2DV/f7b5cff477.png)

So,any suggestion how to do that in code to create better performance.i mean do i need to store data first in some array and display them in the table view.All i need is four data from the body "vendorName,image0,mileage,modelName".So there are one image view,three labels in the table view as i show at above figure.Any Code Help and Suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: There is plenty of discussion about how to read data from JSON. All you have to do then is to keep what info seems important, and may discard (not keep) the useless one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have asked several questions I will answer them. I assume that you are aware how to read data from JSON (you don't have that specific question). So, let me paste some of your text

> Everytime i request,it give me 15 results.All i want is to show this in
> table view using table cell,label and image view like this
>
> So,any suggestion how to do that in code to create better
> performance.i mean do i need to store data first in some array and
> display them in the table view.All i need is four data from the body
> "vendorName,image0,mileage,modelName".So there are one image
> view,three labels in the table view as i show at above figure.Any Code
> Help and Suggestion is appreciated.

First, if you want to get less results, it's not your app that decides. That's the server side. You will have to implement method (or change existing one) to get wanted results.

Second, if you want to manipulate data, one way or another, you will have to store it somewhere. It will be pretty expensive if you have to call API for each cell(or, as reused cells are dequeued anyway). You can store it in array, and maybe implement pull to refresh to reload the list etc.

Third, if you want only several items, again, you will have to change the server. Maybe create function for list, maybe edit one of the function. One way or another, you will have to deal with server.

Additionally, you can deal with all these data by extracting data you want and creating view-purpose model only if you don't have access to server and have work around. You could also load all the data you get from the server, but that can be slow, expensive memory-wise etc.

My suggestion is to create model with 4 attributes you mentioned plus ID, and on `didSelectCellAtRow` get that particular object (car) and then show all the info.

Comment: thanks Nick...that suggestion help me alot and also clear for a newbie to understand.So if i have the question to ask,can i put the link to the question in this comment?

Comment: NickCatib....i ask a question about api call.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28449654/found-nil-while-upwrapping-an-optional-value