# Found nil while upwrapping an Optional value

Tags: json, swift

When i create output of data which you can see at println(data),i get the data.I am trying to get the data from web service.But,why the fatal error occur when parsing the data to JSON.Any help???coding help & suggestion is appreciated.

```
import Foundation

protocol AuctionAPIProtocol{
    func didReceiveAPIResults(results: NSDictionary)
}

class AuctionAPI{

var delegate: AuctionAPIProtocol

init(delegate: AuctionAPIProtocol){
    self.delegate=delegate
}

func get(path:String){
    let url = NSURL(string:path)
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
        println("Task Completed!!!")
        if(error != nil){
            println(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        var err: NSError?
        println(data)
        var jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &err) as NSDictionary
        //var jsonResult=JSON(data!)
        if(err != nil) {
            // If there is an error parsing JSON, print it to the console
            println("JSON Error \(err!.localizedDescription)")
        }
        let results: NSArray = jsonResult["body"] as NSArray
        self.delegate.didReceiveAPIResults(jsonResult)
    })
    task.resume()
}

func searchAuctionLatestFor(){
    let urlPath = "http://xxxxxxxxxxxxx/ws/m/automobile/global/latest/search"
    get(urlPath)
}

//TODO detail func
//func latestDetail(collectionId: Int){
//   get("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
//}
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to curl JSON or to use Advanced Rest Client to get data from server ? Advanced Rest Client is extension for chrome that you can install and debug rest API

Answer (score 0):

You are not checking if the `JSON` parsing has failed in the error before unwrapping the `jsonResult`. Try the following function and see the logged errors.

```
func get(path:String){
    let url = NSURL(string:path)
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
        if(error != nil){
            println(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        var err: NSError?
        let jsonResult: AnyObject? = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &err)
        if(err != nil) {
            println("JSON Error \(err!.localizedDescription)")
        }
        else  {
            if let jsonData = jsonResult as? [String:AnyObject] {
                let results: NSArray = jsonData["body"] as NSArray
                self.delegate.didReceiveAPIResults(jsonData)
            }
        }

    })
    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: use jsonData instead of jsonResult in that line

Comment: The Console Log says....Task Completed!!!
JSON Error The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)

Comment: that means there is something wrong with the json you are getting